# Get value from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

When I check value of an array using var_dump() function.

```
var_dump($data['content']);
```

I have result

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["IDUser"]=> string(1) "1" ["Name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["Password"]=> string(32) "44ca5fa5c67e434b9e779c5febc46f06" ["Fullname"]=> string(18) "Nguyễn Tá Lợi" ["Gender"]=> string(1) "0" ["Birthday"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["Address"]=> string(0) "" ["Email"]=> string(0) "" ["PhoneNumber"]=> string(0) "" ["Status"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

I want get value with key ["Name"] so I use `$data['content']['Name']` but it's incorrect
How to get value of "Name" in this array?

Comment: Use `$data['content'][0]['Name']`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul: I got it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$data['content'][0]['Name']` should do it

Answer (score 2):

Value of `Name` is available on **0** index of `content` so you can not get the Name value as:

```
$data['content']['Name']
```

**You need to get Name as:**

```
$data['content'][0]['Name'] // add 0 index of content.
```